# How to edit footer in RMarkdown using the fancyhdr package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have created a PDF in RMarkdown with the `fancyhdr` package in LaTeX. I'm trying to find a solution in which I can insert a horizontal line as a footer (just above the page number), as well as the page number in the right hand corner similar to the image I have attached. Additionally, is there a way in which I can change the color of all the hyperlinks (such as the table of contents) from the default black color to the same color as in the image?

My YAML is as follows

```
---
title: "Template for a Dynamic Report for Work"
Uni_Logo: Tex/logo.jpg
Author1: "Tangeni Shatiwa" 
# ----- Manage headers and footers:
#BottomLFooter: $Title$
#BottomCFooter:
#TopLHeader: \leftmark # Adds section name at topleft. Remove comment to add it.
BottomRFooter: "\\footnotesize Page \\thepage" # Add a '#' before this line to remove footer.
addtoprule: TRUE
addfootrule: TRUE               # Use if footers added. Add '#' to remove line.
toc: TRUE
numbersections: TRUE             # Should sections (and thus figures and tables) be numbered?
fontsize: 11pt                  # Set fontsize
linestretch: 1.2                # Set distance between lines.
link-citations: TRUE   # This creates dynamic links to the papers in reference list.
linkcolor: blue
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "header.tex"
---
```

and the contents of the `header.tex` file are as follows

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width = .2\textwidth]{logo.jpg}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{logo.jpg}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
```

TIA!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example `rmarkdown` document and `header.tex` file. I removed the logo lines in `header.tex` since I don't have your logo. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

### `rmarkdown` file

```
---
title: "Template for a Dynamic Report for Work"
Author1: "Tangeni Shatiwa" 
BottomRFooter: "\\footnotesize Page \\thepage" # Add a '#' before this line to remove footer.
addtoprule: TRUE
addfootrule: TRUE               # Use if footers added. Add '#' to remove line.
toc: TRUE
numbersections: TRUE             # Should sections (and thus figures and tables) be numbered?
fontsize: 11pt                  # Set fontsize
linestretch: 1.2                # Set distance between lines.
link-citations: TRUE   # This creates dynamic links to the papers in reference list.
urlcolor: darkred
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "header.tex"
---

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

Some text

[This is a link to Stack Overflow](www.stackoverflow.com)

Some more text

\newpage

Even more text
---

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

Some text

[This is a link to Stack Overflow](www.stackoverflow.com)

Some more text

\newpage

Even more text
```

### `header.tex` file

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[L]{This is the left footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
%\lhead{\includegraphics[width = .2\textwidth]{logo.jpg}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  %\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{logo.jpg}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}
```

### PDF output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted, thank you @eipi10! Is there any way that I can include the word "page" before every page number?